# iframe on Android browser issue

Tags: android, iframe

http://fc.wx198.cn/ideaidev/wxsite/14/index.html

I have this web page running on Android.

My phone is Nexus 4 & Android 4.4.

That web page is totally ok with my phone and iphone browser.

but when my co-workers open that page on their mobile phones(Android 4.1/4.2 etc..)

All the Android phone that version below 4.4.

you can see there's a iframe in that page. that iframe is not showing!

I just can't figure out why. help please.

Comment: I've tested your link on my PC and phone. Iframe perfectly visible. Phone running android 2.3/

Comment: can you test on android 4.1/4.2?

Comment: For real, can't see iframe when using 4.1.2 tablet. Try to set background color for iframe to see, if it disappear at all or just page doesn't load.

Comment: @Valentin i just set background color on iframe. also does not showing on android 4.1/4.2

Comment: So, this can mean that browser in android 15-17 doesn't support iframe tag.

Answer (score 4):

I've done some search and it seems that android 4.1/4.2 doesn't include support of iframe tag in built-in browser. You can use javascript and XMLHttpRequest to overcome this obstacle.

Create container for you "iframe" document, then make request and place response in this container. Unfotunately, XMLHttpRequest can only load pages in same domain.

Assume you have div with id `my-iframe` in HTML, js code to load contents of `example.com/frame.html` could be this:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.getElementById("my-iframe").innerHTML = this.responseText;
});
r.open("get", "example.com/frame.html", true);
r.send();
```

edit:fixed syntax

Comment: That is a really interesting solution. In Phonegap there is no limitation on pages you can XHR to - so it could be used as iframe replacement. Just beware of cross site scripting!

Comment: Definitely an interesting method.  I'm +1'ing you just because it's a cool concept.  Don't think it would play to nicely if the iframe you're loading was an html5 video, but normal html content should load fine.